# Change desktop web pages to mobile web pages when someone logs in using mobile

Tags: css, django, web, mobile

I have developed some site using Django. It works fine for desktop. But on mobile i need to zoom out to view the page.

Can anyone help me with **settings to be added for changing desktop web pages to mobile pages** so that they will get fit in mobile screen size?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS flex layouts work for this well. Details can be found here. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Can I see the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries and device width meta tag to make your web page get fit in mobile also.

Here is reference: `https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp`

Hope this will help you any comment or query welcome..

Comment: Meta tag as mentioned by @Divya..use this tag before head of the web page..

Comment: Hi Sangrai.Thanks for the help.I am using one "header.html" in which one header,one container and one footer is available.Container will load web pages as per user choice.So I am little confused where to add settings in both pages or in header only.Secondly Do I need to prepare two separate pages for desktop and mobile.

Comment: No you don't need to setup separate pages for desktop and mobile use the css file to control  desktop and mobile version of web page.

Comment: Thanks.Then How can I achieve that.